# Problem detecting wireless networks on a Dell Inspiron 1420

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, dell, inspiron

my Dell inspiron 1420 running Ubuntu 11.10 [as of today] cannot detect any wireless networks [and I know there are some in range]. Perhaps a problem with the proprietary driver? How should I go about fixing this?  I really have no idea=am linux illiterate

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Can you try this and then edit your question with what happens? http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-a-graphics-or-wireless-card-driver

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has a program called "Restircted Drivers". If you have a Broadcom Wireless card (many Dell notebooks have Broadcom), you can found the needed drivers there. You only have to activate it; Ubuntu will download it and install it.

Try this possible fix. Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post would be helpful.

http://blog.tech4him.com/2011/09/broadcom-wireless-on-ubuntu-11-04-and-11-10/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.